# How to find the business day of the previous year (or closest of the week before if weekend)

Tags: python, pandas, date

I'm trying to find previous year business day. If the day falls on a weekend, I want the last valid business day.

Below is my sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime as dt
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['20210625','20220626'],'Amount':[10,20]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
date_1 = df['Date'].iloc[-1]
date_2 = date_1 - pd.DateOffset(years=1)
df_2 = df[df['Date'] == date_2]
df_2
```

So what I need is that how to find `date_2` as the recent business date of the same date of last year.
In this case, the expected output would be `2021-06-25` (Fri) -> `2020-06-25` (Thu) and `2022-06-26` (Sun) -> `2021-06-25` (Fri).

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit the question? For instance, you're mentioning the "*last date*", but `2021-06-25` is not. What happens to the second date? What would be the expected output if you had more rows?

Comment: Thank for your response, sorry for that my question is not clear for you. So what I need is that find the business date of the same date of last year. For example in my case, If I just use DateOffset, it will return `2021-06-26` but it's not the business date so nothing shows. So I need to by the day before of it.

Comment: Can you have a look at my answer? It's giving you the business day of the **previous year**, for instance `2021-06-25` -> `2020-06-25`, if this is not what you want please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear, I'll answer the How to find the "*recent business date of the same date of last year*" part:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay

df['lastYear'] = df['Date']-pd.DateOffset(years=1)+0*BDay()
```

output:

```
        Date  Amount   lastYear
0 2021-06-25      10 2020-06-25
1 2022-06-26      20 2021-06-28
```

##### previous BDay if not a BDay:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay

df['lastYear'] = df['Date']-BDay(1)-pd.DateOffset(years=1)+BDay(1)
```

output (with more examples):

```
        Date  Amount   lastYear
0 2021-06-25      10 2020-06-25
1 2022-06-24      20 2021-06-24
2 2022-06-25      30 2021-06-25
3 2022-06-26      40 2021-06-25
4 2022-06-27      50 2021-06-25
5 2022-06-28      60 2021-06-28
```